# How to have padding and margin for a border when composite an image over another one?

Tags: imagemagick, padding, margin

I'm trying to composite a legend on top of a graph using ImageMagick:

`magick composite -gravity southeast '.\legend.png' -bordercolor black -border 1x1 '.\graph.png' '.\final.png'`

[image]

As you can see the border doesn't have any padding or margin so it's not quite nice looking. However searching in the [ImageMagick – Command-line Options](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) page I see no option for those. Is there a way to do that?

This is my desired output. Notice the padding inside the box and the margin outside the box:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, set -gravity southeast for the bottom left alignment and also -geometry +X+Y for the X and Y offset from the bottom left to move it up and or to the left.

`convert backgroundimage legendimage -geometry +10+10 -gravity southeast -compose over -composite resultimage`

If you need to add a (10 px) border inside the borderline (assume 1 px thick) of your overlay (legend), then in Unix syntax:

```
convert backgroundimage \
\( legendimage -shave 1x1 \
-bordercolor white -border 10x10 \
-bordercolor black -border 1x1 \) \
-geometry +10+10 -gravity southeast \
-compose over -composite resultimage
```

Comment: I see. That's for margin. How about padding?

Comment: What is the point of padding (apart from the margin offset) if the padding is white and the background is white? The padding and margin do the same thing. What is it exactly that you want with respect to your image above? Adding padding outside your black border around the legend is no different from the margin offset. If you have something else in mind, please clarify and post the two input images and your desired output.

Comment: isn't that padding is the space inside the border and margin is the space outside the border? I've added the desired output, can you check?

Comment: If your overlay image (legend) has a border and you want inside padding, then you would need to strip the border (-shave), then add the padding (-border), then add the borderline (-border). See my addition to my answer above

Comment: using a white thick border as padding. Genius